# Titles truncated automatically

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am having a strange issue. The titles that I specify in toolbar or in Ext.Msg.alert is automatically truncated and a '...' is appended.

[image]

How to get rid of this? I want full titles in Toolbar, message boxes and everywhere else.

Comment: In above case my title was "Invoice"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in Webkit which are reported in sencha's forum that you can refer it [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228621-Short-titles-in-title-bar-also-gets-clipped-with-text-ellipsis) or [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?234790-Why-titlebar-s-title-cuts-off-after-23-chars):

Use this in your `css` or `.sass` file as a solution:

```
.x-title{padding:0 .3em;}
.x-title .x-innerhtml{padding: 0;}
```

Or:

```
.x-title .x-innerhtml:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';       
    width: 0.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of ellipsis property assigned to .x-title by default. You need to change that to to clip property.

Give a cls property to your config.

For example :

cls : 'textFormat',

Then in a css file :

```
.textFormat .x-title .x-innerhtml{
    text-overflow : clip !important;
 }
```

This code will override the existing code for the particular toolbar.